# JQuery - Remove all option from Selectbox except for first and selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html select box with several options. Upon selection of an option I want Only the selected option and the first option to be shown in the select option dropdown. I know how to filter and show only one option but I cannot figure out how to include both option where the 'selected' option remains 'selected'. I have include snippets similar to of my code as well as a demo.

HTML:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
<option selected>Select fruit</option>
<option>Grapes</option>
<option>Bananas</option>
<option>Oranges</option>
<option>Apples</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '#myDropdown', function() {
    $('option', this).not(this,'option:gt(0)').siblings().remove(); });
```

I am trying to use the first option to perform another function 'on change' so I need the selected option to remain selected while the rest being filtered out except for the first. For example if 'Oranges' were selected, this is what you would see:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
     <option>Select fruit</option>
     <option>Oranges</option>  //selcted value
</select>
```

BTW I am using jquery mobile to style as well.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znx9hxvu/8/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) only takes 1 parameter. If you want to filter on two different selectors, you can add a comma between them inside the string. You can also use the [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
$('option', this).not(':eq(0), :selected').remove();
```

See Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znx9hxvu/9/

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.